# Giving sense to a sum over an uncountable set of elements which are equal to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-walk

Let $(X_i)$ be a simple random walk in $\mathbb{Z}$ starting from the origin. Let $\Sigma$ be the set whose elements are $(Y_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, which are infinite random walk trajectories. Consider an event $\mathcal{A} \subset \Sigma$.
We have that, since we sum over the probability of disjoint events,
$$
P(A) = \sum\limits_{(Y_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N} }\in \mathcal{A}} P(X_i = Y_i \, \, \, \forall i \in \mathbb{N} ).
$$

Now the sum on the right hand side is uncountable and each probability on the right hand side equals zero. So does the expression make sense? How is it possible to give sense to it? Should I write it as an integral over all possible trajectories?

Comment: The sum of some nonnegative terms over an uncountable set S can be defined as the supremum of the sums restricted to the countable subsets of S. Such sums can only be finite if the set of nonzero terms is at most countable.